# Dynamic Meteor template content in Bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap tabs in Meteor. I have an images list table in first tab and when the user clicks a row in the image list, Thumbnails template will be added to a new tab and it will show the row's images as thumbnails. I am using `UI.insert( UI.render( Template.Thumbnails ), $("#thumbnails").get(0))` to show template in the tab. I am setting a Session holds images json object when the user clicks the row and getting the Session in Thumbnails template and showing images. When I select a new row from images list at the first tab, Session value is changed and content of previous tabs and last tab is the same. Any advice to solve this problem?

Comment: Really not clear what the problem is. With bootstrap tabs you can easily control which tab is shown without a session variable. You might need a session variable to remember what row was clicked on but even that you could do with a closure. Perhaps you can make a Meteorpad to show what's going on?

Comment: Hi @MichelFloyd, Thank you for your response. I fixed the problem.